# Hide / Reveal Divs not side by side

Tags: html, css-float, show-hide

I am trying to do a hide / reveal using javascript and css and my divs are stacking rather than lining up side by side. i have set a width and floats... i cant figure out what's going on. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#container {
width: 760px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 30px;
background-color: #000;
border-width: 0px;
color: #fff;
}
#1a {
width: 300px;
float: left;
margin:10px
background-color: #000;
}

#1b {
width: 400px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: #000;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="1b" class="hidden">
Module Details:
My First Page
</div>
<div id="1a">
<a href="javascript:unhide('1b');">01</a>
</div>
```

i've been messing with it a lot, and now the second div is in the middle of the first... so here is a link if that's helpful too:
http://www.amandasmithsf.com/m14_SMITH_demo/test.html

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Inspecting your CSS in Firebug, I noticed that it wasn't being applied, then I saw why -- HTML IDs should not start with a number (or at least, not if you want them to work the CSS `#` selector; it turns out that in HTML5 they decided to start allowing IDs beginning with numbers, but you'll have to use a different strategy to select them with CSS: http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/).

Starting the IDs with letters instead of numbers made it work:

```
<style>
.hidden {display:none}

#container {
width: 760px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 30px;
background-color: #000;
border-width: 0px;
color: #fff;
}
#b1 {
float: left;
width: 300px;
margin:10px;
background-color: #000;
}
#a1 {
float:left;
width: 10px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: #000;
}
</style>
<script>
function unhide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="b1" class="hidden">
    Module Details:
    My First Page
    </div>
    <div id="a1">
    <a href="javascript:unhide('b1');">01</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Original Answer**

I think you just need to add `float: left;` to `#1b`.

Or, if for some reason you really only wanted to assign `float: left;` to one of them, it would need to be `#1b` - the floated element needs to come before the non-floated element next to which you want it to display.

Comment: i tried putting 1a before 1b, putting the float on just one, on both. nothing fixes it. i'm befuddled.